# Need help with finder method using >= comparison rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app that lists a bands shows in an unordered list on the home page.

```
<ul>
 <% for show in @shows %>
   <li>
     <strong><%= link_to show.venue, show %></strong><br />
     <%= display_date(show.show_date) %>
   </li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

There is a shows controller that handles creating the shows. It has rows in the database like venue, show_date, show_time, and so on. The home page of the app comes from a pages controller. The pages controller has two actions that create the home page and the about page.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController 
  def home
    @shows = Show.find(:all, :order => :show_date)
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

The problem I'm having is that I only want the shows with a show_date greater than or equal to Date.today to be populated into the @shows instance variable that will in turn be populated into the unordered list. Any help writing a custom finder method would be greatly appreciated. Would it be easier to filter through the @shows variable using a helper method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to filter out dates (this uses Rails 3's newer `where(...)` syntax instead of `find(:all...)`).

```
@shows = Show.where("show_date >= ?", Date.today).order(:show_date)
```

Also, in your `Show` model you could add a named scope so you can reuse this in other places:

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :upcoming, lambda { where("show_date >= ?", Date.today).order(:show_date) }
end
```

Then in your controller, you could just do:

```
@shows = Show.upcoming
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and works beautifully! The scope is genius! Thanks Dylan

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Show.all(:order => 'show_date desc')
```

or in Rails 3

```
Show.order('show_date desc').all
```

Comment: The ordering of the records is working fine I want to remove the shows with a date older than today's date so it won't list them in the unordered list. I don't want to remove them from the database just not list them.

Comment: Not a problem Joel, thanks for your answer anyway! Dylan gave the perfect answer above.